# iOS app beta update page broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Such a fragile page it is, broken yet again. I'm not including a link since I believe it's still security through obscurity, but the entirety of the page for downloading beta app updates reads:

```
{"error_id":500,"error_message":"this error has been logged","error_name":"internal_error"}
```

Comment: True, and for some reason when clicking the "Update Now" via the app when it says the version is outdated, it's opening in Safari and not in Chrome like it always used to do.

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2975364#2975364 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed.  The build server was updated and the artifacts (files) from the last build weren't available.  Since mobile.SE [is mostly there to host web services](https://mobile.stackexchange.com) you got the same error response we send to the app when things like the feed are down.

The page is back up but we are having a temporary issue with the service we pull version numbers from so you may see "Version 0.0.0" for a while.  Similarly while that part is broken you won't see new update notices in the app.

Either that or this has all been an elaborate rouse to make everyone appreciate the new "Later" button in the update alert. :)

Comment: it sure was perfect timing to let us skip updates!

Comment: Truth be told, if you just tapped "Update now" and switched back to the app you could keep using it.

Comment: Yeah I've done that a lot throughout the beta